# Xamarin.Forms Service return List<T> plus Status Code

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, http-status-codes

This is the code from the service i generated.Everything work fine. I get the list of photos, but i want to get the status_code and make logic in the ViewModel and show message to the user.

```
 public async Task<IList<Photo>> GetAllPosts()
        {
            try
            {
                if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
                {
                    instagramCloneClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                    instagramCloneClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
                    var response = await instagramCloneClient.GetAsync($"/photos");
                    var status_code=(int)response.StatusCode;
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string jsonMessage;
                        using (Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                        {
                            jsonMessage = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
                        }

                        IList<Photo> photos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Photo>>(jsonMessage);
                        return photos;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                string error = ex.Message;
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I return list of photos. I also want `response.StatusCode` to the `ViewModel` from which i call the function.I must return IList, how to include some `int status_code`? What is the best practice?

Comment: generally, you would return a wrapper object that contains both status info and the data, OR if there is a failure you can throw an exception instead of returning the data

Comment: @Jason u mean like Object witch contain IList<Photos> and int status_code?

Comment: yes, a custom class that contains whatever set of data and status info you want to return to the caller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options. You can create a new model with your List and an integer/enum for the StatusCode. Another option is to return a List of ArrayList.